# cassandra.yaml changes not working at all

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Im new using Cassandra 3.11.4, and just installed it on a ubuntu VM, and following the instructions, I tried to change the cluster name on the .yaml config file, but when I save the doc, and go Start Cassandra, it throws a failure, and this happens with anything I change on the .yaml file, it just doesn't work the way documentation says it should(I located the Cassandra files in a location where my user has all permissions)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C72JH.png). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F330K.png)

If I make no changes to the file, and Start Cassandra, it does successfully.

I found out that I can change the cluster name or listen address, or any other parameter listed on the .yaml file successfully after connecting the database and querying for example

`update cluster_name from system.local where cluster_name='Test Cluster';`

but that's not the point of having the .yaml conf file.

Does someone know why this happens?
I've had this issue even using other Cassandra versions, like 3.11.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra you can't simply change some configuration parameters and except it to work after restart. `cluster_name` is not specific to the node. It is applicable to entire cluster. parameters like `data_file_directories` can be changed at node level.

And if you want to change the name of cluster it is whole different process. Refer below link

> https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205289825-Change-Cluster-Name-